# Further aggregate date histogram in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to extract, for each `event_type`, in how many days the event occurred and the last occurrence. Currently I wrote the following query:

```
{
    "size": 0,
    "query": { ... },
    "_source": false,
    "aggregations": {
        "events": { 
            "terms": { "field": "event_type" },
            "aggs": {
                "event_timestamp": {
                    "date_histogram": {
                        "field": "@timestamp",
                        "calendar_interval": "day",
                        "min_doc_count": 1,
                        "order": { "_key": "desc" }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

that extracts data to be further transformed. In my case, I just need, for each `event_type`, the key of the first `event_timestamp` bucket and the number of `event_timestamp` buckets. This can be done easily in a second step after this extraction, but it would be cleaner to let Elastic do it.

[Max bucket](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-max-bucket-aggregation.html) (or metric) aggregation does not seems helpful, as I don't see a suitable `buckets_path` in the `date_histogram` aggregation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good start!!

Here is a query that returns you the latest timestamp per `event_type` as well as the number of daily buckets for each `event_type` (for this you can use the [`bucket_script` pipeline aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-script-aggregation.html) which simply returns the [number of buckets](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline.html#_special_paths) in the `date_histogram` aggregation).

Also note that the `filter_path` query string parameter allows you to only return what matters to you, i.e. you can get rid of the date histogram that you're not interested in:

```
POST test/_search?filter_path=**.latest_timestamp.hits.hits._source,**.bucket_count,**.events.buckets.key
{
  "size": 0,
  "_source": false,
  "query": {...},
  "aggregations": {
    "events": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "event_type"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "latest_timestamp": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1,
            "sort": {"@timestamp": "desc"}, 
            "_source": ["@timestamp"]
          }
        },
        "event_timestamp": {
          "date_histogram": {
            "field": "@timestamp",
            "calendar_interval": "day",
            "min_doc_count": 1,
            "order": {
              "_key": "desc"
            }
          }
        },
        "bucket_count": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "count": "event_timestamp._bucket_count"
            },
            "script": "params.count"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You'll get for each event type something that looks like this:

```
    {
      "key": "2",                            <--- event type
      "latest": {
        "hits": {
          "hits": [
            {
              "_source": {
                "@timestamp": "2023-01-05"   <--- latest timestamp
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "bucket_count": {
        "value": 4                           <--- bucket count
      }
    },
```

Comment: Thank you! A note: what I need in the bucket count is "count": "event_timestamp._bucket_count"

Comment: Yes, that's what _count returns already, see my updated answer

Comment: No, I see some difference: _count returns the doc count and not the bucket count

Comment: My bad, you're right, it's fixed  I tested with a unique document per day, hence the confusion, sorry